# Doxygen how to avoid line break spacing

Tags: doxygen, line-breaks, spacing

How is it possible if I want to force a new line break via `<br>` or `\n` in doxygen to avoid the line spacing, e.g. for an address?

Comment: Are you facing the same kind of problem than mine? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21977016/avoid-line-break-in-doxygen-output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doxygen understands HTML and will insert a line break with `<br>`.   See: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/htmlcmds.html

Comment: I've see this, but this is a line break with space between two lines. I don't want to have so many spaces e.g. for an address.

Comment: What version of doxygen are you using?   With 1.7.6 I have an address formatted as separate lines (Name, Address, City) with <br> at the end of each.   This renders as expected, as consecutive lines with no additional space between lines.

Comment: @MarcelHöll Paul is correct, and you can also use `\n`. To me, they appear to only remove a single line. Sounds more like your browser's problem to me, or Doxygen version (mine is 1.8.10).