# Avoid line break in doxygen output

Tags: doxygen

I just realized that I can write part of the doxygen documentation inside the method implementation, which seems to be a very good way to have an accurate documentation!

One little thing that bother me is that I would like to avoid line breaking when writing a sentence on multiple line:

```
/// Check if the pointer is not null,
if( ptr != ) {
    /// increment it
    ptr++
    /// and perform other stupid task...
    ...
}
```

This would generate 3 differents lines but I would like it to stick it on one. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you ask for is not possible, but if you want such detailed implementation comments, the reader probably wants to see the code as well, so in that case I suggest to use normal `//` comments and enable `INLINE_SOURCES` in the configuration file.

Comment: I'm very pleased to have an answer from the lead developer of this great tool! Thanks :-)

Comment: Totally different question: I asked github support recently if they had in plan a better integration of code documentation in their platform and they were interested. Don't you think there could be something nice to do around this idea?